# async await is not in hold state mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I don't know why first it prints `data return` instead of after loop done

code

```
exports.put = async function (req, res, next) {
    const data = Array.from(req.body);
    let errors = false;
    data.forEach(async (update, index) => {
        try {
            const result = await TypeofAccount.findByIdAndUpdate(
                new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(update._id),
                {
                    $set: { name: update.name },
                },
                { new: true, runValidators: true },
            );
            console.log(index);
            if (!result) {
                errors = true;
                console.log('errors');
                return res.status(500).send();
            }
        } catch (e) {
            return res.status(500).send();
        }
    });
    console.log('data return');
    res.json(data);
};
```

- data return
- PUT /api//typeofaccount 200 5.551 ms - 202
- 0
- 1
- 2

Comment: Marking the callback function passed to `forEach()` as `async` only makes that callback return a promise, it doesn't make `forEach()` run asynchronously.

Comment: Thank you @BilalAkbar, it is working fine with for of, strange behavior of javascript, i have been thinking it should run after forEach

Comment: It's perfectly logical behavior once you understand how `async-await` actually works. Keep in mind that unlike `for-of`, `forEach()` isn't a language feature, it's part of the array API.

Answer (score 0):

The .for each function runs asynchronously and that is why you can see the console.log which is after the loop get printed first

Comment: "*runs on another thread*" - no, definitely not.

Comment: I am sorry I didn't put it correctly but I meant that it runs asynchronously and that's why the code below it prints first

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to fix the wording then

Answer (score 0):

this problem happened becouse you are use `forEach` loop , asyc await not working with `forEach` , to avoid this problem your code block should be like

```
for(let i in data){
try {
            const result = await TypeofAccount.findByIdAndUpdate(
                new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(data[i]._id),
                {
                    $set: { name: data[i].name },
                },
                { new: true, runValidators: true },
            );
            console.log(i);
            if (!result) {
                errors = true;
                console.log('errors');
                return res.status(500).send();
            }
        } catch (e) {
            return res.status(500).send();
        }
}
```